# Bug when displaying Configurable Product simple tier prices

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, tierprice

I have a Mag 2 site which uses configurable products, some of these use tier pricing for the simple products. If I have a tier price which uses the fixed option the following code in final_price.phtml displays the price correctly eg "From $7.75 inc tax"

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
```

If the simple product uses the discount(%) tier price option the same code above displays the from price as "From $0.00 inc tax".

I've been through the code and try to modify it but I can't get the from price to be displayed correctly when a simple product uses the discount(%) tier price option.